# if devise gem exists put before_action :authenticate_user! otherwise leave out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a rails engine I'd like to make more universal. I have before_action :authenticate_user! in my controllers for devise.

Is there a way I can put if devise gem exists put before_action :authenticate_user! otherwise leave out.

Comment: Try `before_action :authenticate_user!, if: :devise_controller?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `defined?` to look for `Devise`:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, if: -> { defined?(Devise) }
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!